# How to correctly pass a string id to API controller in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, api, xamarin.forms, mobile, webapi

I'm writing a mobile app using Xamarin Forms where I am going to consume an REST API.

At the moment, I have a user model

```
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserDisplayName { get; set; }
        public int UserRoleId { get; set; }
        public string UserFirstName { get; set; }
        public string UserLastName { get; set; }
        public string UserEmail { get; set; }
        public string UserPostcode { get; set; }
        public DateTime UserCreatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime UserModifiedAt { get; set; }
        public bool UserDeletedAt { get; set; }
    }
```

And I have defined a GetUser method on my controller

```
 // GET: api/Users/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<User>> GetUser(string id)
        {
            
            var user = await _context.User.FindAsync(id);

            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return user;
        }
```

If I test the API using Postman and parse the string id without quotes(edit) on the route, it works fine. E.g. https://localhost:5051/api/Users/Example. However, if I parse the id within qutoes(edit) it doesn't work: https://localhost:5051/api/Users/"Example"

My problem is, on my mobile client, when it calls the web service that calls the API, it needs to parse a string, which goes with the quotes(edit)- matching the second example.

Does any of you know a solution or a workaround for this?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

My service method is as follows

```
     public static async Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetUserById(string id)
        {           
            var json = await client.GetStringAsync($"api/users/{id}");
            var users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<User>>(json);
            return users;
        }
```

And my service call is

`var users = await UserService.GetUserById("Example");`

EDIT2: Fixed

Service method changed to

```
     public static async Task<User> GetUserById(string id)
        {           
            var json = await client.GetStringAsync($"api/users/{id}");
            var users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json);
            return users;
        }
```

Comment: first, these `"` are "quotes", not "commas".  This `,` is a "comma".  Second, it's not clear why you can't use "/api/Users/Example" in your mobile client.  Can you post some code that illustrates the problem?

Comment: parsedString.Trim('"'), but there are also other characters that you can not use within routeparameters. But providing them in the query as encoded values will work allways

Comment: @Jason - Didn't realize I was typing "commas" instead of "quotes", my bad. I've edited the question with the service method and service call. I hope it helps to illustrate the problem?!

Comment: no, it doesn't.  `GetUserById("Example")` will result in the url `api/users/Example` - how is that causing a problem?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something very obvious, it appears to be resulting in the URL api/users/"Example", which returns a "not found". I don't have my working machine now and I'll be able to double-check in a couple of hours from now. I'll report back if I find anything. Thanks

Comment: I don't see how that could happen.  This is basic C# string handling.  Try assigning `$"api/users/{id}"` to a variable and writing it to the console to verify.

Comment: That is quite odd indeed, are you sure that the id itself isn't "Example" with the strings as part of its value? As Jason said, otherwise nothing else might explain the issue.

Comment: Hi all. Thanks for the comments. It turns out the issue was caused by the IEnumerable type on the task definition, which makes sense since I was trying to retrieve a single instance. Changed it to Task<User> and it works now. Cheers!

Comment: Please post the fix as an answer to the question. (Yes, you can answer your own question.)  This way, people scanning the open questions will know it has been answered. Also, after 48 hours, you can accept your own answer. Please do so then.

Comment: BTW, that sometimes won't be a valid URL, given an arbitrary string... Google for information about URL Encoding.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue was caused by the IEnumerable type on the task definition, which makes sense since I was trying to retrieve a single instance.

Service method changed to

```
     public static async Task<User> GetUserById(string id)
        {           
            var json = await client.GetStringAsync($"api/users/{id}");
            var users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json);
            return users;
        }
```